# How to stop Java recursion in Finding Peak inside 2D Array

Tags: java, recursion, 2d

so I've been trying to perfect this method for a good amount of time now but I cannot make it work. What I'm trying to do is find a peak number in a 2D array of different integers using recursion only in Java.

Basically what my method does it check if the indexes are inside the array and if the numbers **above,below,left and right** to it are **bigger** than the current number.

If they are, the recursion prints the current point and continues. However, with the code I have written, the method finds the first path and then for some reason **goes back and finds a different path** which generates problems, I want only **one** path to be printed and then the method needs to stop.

I have tried putting a boolean to check if there is a peak and then return true but it still goes back and prints the other paths. If you guys could help me, it would be amazing.

This is the code:

```
private static void printPath (int[][] mat, int i, int j) {

    System.out.println("("+i+","+j+")");

    if (i >=0 && i < mat.length-1 && mat[i][j] < mat[i+1][j]){
        printPath(mat,i+1,j);
    }
    if (j >=0 && j < mat[0].length-1 && mat[i][j] < mat[i][j+1]){
        printPath(mat,i,j+1);
    }
    if (i>0 && i < mat.length-1 && mat[i][j] < mat[i-1][j]){
        printPath(mat,i-1,j);
    }
    if (j>0 && j < mat[0].length-1 && mat[i][j] < mat[i][j-1]){
        printPath(mat,i,j-1);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for any one of the possible paths and not the path that has the largest values, I have a simple solution.

Just make the remaining **if** statements as **else if** statements. You enforce the program to only follow one path in each call of your recursive function

Comment: Oh my god, I feel like such an idiot. This was correct for how I wanted the method to work, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you change the whole algorithm?

1. Flatten the matrix into a 1D array of `m*n` size by appending `m` arrays of `n` items one after another.
2. Use simple `max` algorithm to find the index of the peak in the flattened array.
3. Convert the index in the flattened array to the point in original matrix:

   ```
   i = index / m
   j = index % m
   ```

**EDIT**

Try putting `else` keywords between those `if`s:

```
private static void printPath (int[][] mat, int i, int j) {

    System.out.println("("+i+","+j+")");

    if (i >=0 && i < mat.length-1 && mat[i][j] < mat[i+1][j]){
        printPath(mat,i+1,j);
    } else if (j >=0 && j < mat[0].length-1 && mat[i][j] < mat[i][j+1]){
        printPath(mat,i,j+1);
    } else if (i>0 && i < mat.length-1 && mat[i][j] < mat[i-1][j]){
        printPath(mat,i-1,j);
    } else if (j>0 && j < mat[0].length-1 && mat[i][j] < mat[i][j-1]){
        printPath(mat,i,j-1);
    }
}
```

But I am still not sure of the algorithm - this will be able to find a local peak, but not global - imagine there is an item that has all the neighbours lower than itself, but somewhere else in the matrix there might be even bigger number. Your alogrithm will stop at this item, even though it is not the biggest one of all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, but the whole idea is to not change the original 2D array.

Comment: @user1930233 why? is the goal the algorithm, not the result?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Do you know why this method doesn't stop at one path?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the else was what I was looking for, I felt so stupid. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it "goes back" is that you have potentially 4 branches on each recursion call. Let's consider an example:

1. First condition is true so the first path begins
2. At some point there is no condition fulfilled and the path ends
3. Program returns to **last frame** ([info](https://www.leepoint.net/JavaBasics/methods/methods-25-calls.html)) and executes the code from where it ended <- this causes your problem

So when the first execution is complete it starts its way back to the start with the possibility to branch again. To fix this you would have to join your condition to one statement so only one recursive call can be fired from your function.

If the branching you have in your function now is desired (I didn't quite get it from the description) you would have to pass additional `boolean` **method parameter** indicating if the further search is needed. You will have to check the endConditon somehow in your method and pass the value accordingly. Of course add this to your method:

```
if (endCondition) return;
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, even though avinash answered my question, your response was helpful as I learned more about recursion and for my future progress in Java, thank you!!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Well... I do not recomend you to just use **else** statements in this case, because with this you will only show the very first high path found. I've rewrited your code to find the highest matrix path. Obviously, it became more complex, but you can assure that the highest path will be found.

```
private static void printPath (int[][] mat, int i, int j) {

    if (mat.length == 0 || mat[0].length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Empty matrix");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("("+i+","+j+")");

    int rightValue = i >=0 && i < mat.length-1 && mat[i][j] < mat[i+1][j] ? mat[i+1][j] : mat[i][j];
    int belowValue = j >=0 && j < mat[0].length-1 && mat[i][j] < mat[i][j+1] ? mat[i][j+1] : mat[i][j];
    int aboveValue = i>0 && i < mat.length-1 && mat[i][j] < mat[i-1][j] ? mat[i-1][j] : mat[i][j];
    int leftValue = j>0 && j < mat[0].length-1 && mat[i][j] < mat[i][j-1] ? mat[i][j-1] : mat[i][j];

    // now you need to iterate over the four values to check wich one is the highest value
    // this way, you will get the highest path... 

    if (rightValue > leftValue) {
        if (rightValue > belowValue) {
            if (rightValue > aboveValue) {
                printPath(mat,i+1,j);
            } else {
                printPath(mat,i,j+1);
            }
        } else {
            if (belowValue > aboveValue) {
                printPath(mat,i-1,j);
            } else {
                printPath(mat,i,j+1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (leftValue > belowValue) {
            if (leftValue > aboveValue) {
                printPath(mat,i-1,j);
            } else {
                printPath(mat,i,j+1);
            }
        } else {
            if (belowValue > aboveValue) {
                printPath(mat,i-1,j);
            } else {
                printPath(mat,i,j+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to find the path that contains the highest values, this will give you the correct output. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I only need the first Peak it finds. That's why adding the else's fixed it for me, but thanks for your input and time!! The method you wrote is very good for improving my own.